# Ошибка при использовании IL2CPP в Unity для компиляции билда под Windows 10

Tags: unity3d

Интересно, сталкивался ли кто-то с такой ошибкой?
SDK Windows 10 устанавливал отдельно от VS. На форумах читал, что должно было вылечить проблему, но не помогло. Что-то все равно не находит.

Сам текст ошибки:

Exception: D:\Unity\2019.4.20f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/deploy/net471/il2cpp.exe did not run properly!

Failed running "D:\Unity\2019.4.20f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/deploy/net471/il2cpp.exe"
--convert-to-cpp --emit-null-checks --enable-array-bounds-check --dotnetprofile="unityaot" --compile-cpp --libil2cpp-static --platform="WindowsDesktop" --architecture="x64" --configuration="Release" --outputpath="D:\UnityProj\TestVS\Temp/StagingArea/Data\Native\GameAssembly.dll"
--cachedirectory="D:\UnityProj\TestVS\Assets..\Library/il2cpp_cache" --profiler-report --map-file-parser=D:/Unity/2019.4.20f1/Editor/Data/Tools/MapFileParser/MapFileParser.exe
--directory=D:/UnityProj/TestVS/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed --generatedcppdir=D:/UnityProj/TestVS/Temp/StagingArea/Data/il2cppOutput

stdout: il2cpp.exe didn't catch exception: System.InvalidOperationException: C++ code builder is unable to build C++ code. In order to build C++ code for Windows Desktop, you must have one of these installed:
Visual Studio 2015 with C++ compilers and Windows 10 SDK (it cannot build C++ code because it is not installed or missing C++ workload component)
Visual Studio 2015 installation is found by looking at "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\InstallDir" in the registry
Windows 10 SDK is found by looking at "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0\InstallationFolder" in the registry

```
    Visual Studio 2017 (or newer) with C++ compilers and Windows 10 SDK (it cannot build C++ code because it is not installed or missing C++ workload component)
    Visual Studio 2017 (or newer) installation is found using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration COM APIs
    Windows 10 SDK is found by looking at "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0\InstallationFolder" in the registry
```

� Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ThrowIfCannotBuildInCurrentEnvironment() � Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics)    � il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args, List`1 foundAssemblies)    � il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args, Boolean setInvariantCulture)    � il2cpp.Program.Main(String[] args) stderr:

����ࠡ�⠭��� �᪫�祭��: System.InvalidOperationException: C++ code builder is unable to build C++ code. In order to build C++ code for Windows Desktop, you must have one of these installed:
Visual Studio 2015 with C++ compilers and Windows 10 SDK (it cannot build C++ code because it is not installed or missing C++ workload component)
Visual Studio 2015 installation is found by looking at "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\InstallDir" in the registry
Windows 10 SDK is found by looking at "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0\InstallationFolder" in the registry

```
    Visual Studio 2017 (or newer) with C++ compilers and Windows 10 SDK (it cannot build C++ code because it is not installed or missing C++ workload component)
    Visual Studio 2017 (or newer) installation is found using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration COM APIs
    Windows 10 SDK is found by looking at "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0\InstallationFolder" in the registry
```

� Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ThrowIfCannotBuildInCurrentEnvironment() � Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics)    � il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args, List`1 foundAssemblies)    � il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args, Boolean setInvariantCulture)    � il2cpp.Program.Main(String[] args)

UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at <8d21067e8d9c494db25a2b2485216e63>:0) UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo) (at <8d21067e8d9c494db25a2b2485216e63>:0) UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.RunIl2CppWithArguments (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] arguments, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo, System.String workingDirectory) (at <8d21067e8d9c494db25a2b2485216e63>:0) UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp (UnityEditor.Il2Cpp.Il2CppBuildPipelineData data, System.String outputDirectory, System.String workingDirectory, System.Boolean platformSupportsManagedDebugging) (at <8d21067e8d9c494db25a2b2485216e63>:0) UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () (at <8d21067e8d9c494db25a2b2485216e63>:0) UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String stagingAreaData, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action`1[T] modifyOutputBeforeCompile, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry) (at <8d21067e8d9c494db25a2b2485216e63>:0) DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.SetupStagingArea (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[T] filesToNotOverwrite) (at <8d21067e8d9c494db25a2b2485216e63>:0) DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at <8d21067e8d9c494db25a2b2485216e63>:0) Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown. DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at <8d21067e8d9c494db25a2b2485216e63>:0) UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <8d21067e8d9c494db25a2b2485216e63>:0) UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <8d21067e8d9c494db25a2b2485216e63>:0) UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение простое. Выбрать при установке Visual Studio:

- Разработка классических приложений на с++

Скорее всего подтягивает необходимый компилятор и заодно Windows SDK ставит.

[image: Visual Studio Installer]